# When I change views from child to parent view, parents' viewWillAppear method not get called

Tags: ios, methods, view, parent

When I change views from child to parent view, parents' viewWillAppear method not get called

This is my code in Parent view.

```
PrivacyViewController *privacy = [[PrivacyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"privacyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:privacy];
[self.view addSubview:privacy.view];
[privacy didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This is my code in Child view.

```
-(IBAction)backButton:(UIButton*)button
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Seems I do it right. 10x

Comment: viewWillAppear will not get call because you are adding/removing subview to a view not navigating from one view to other view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent's `viewWillAppear` methods is not called when you modify its view.
It is called only when it is showed, not when someone modify its view.

When you use the `addChildViewController` method, the viewWillAppear method is called on the child, not on the parent.

Comment: In that case how do I find out what is the current view? I have to add Google analytics in my app that's why I need to know that. I'm new in this. 10x again.

Comment: You have to manage it manually: your container controller have to manage it manually, saving the controller instance when showing it.